# Proving $\cos x$ has a unique fixed point

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I am trying to prove that the function $\cos x$ has a unique fixed point. Certainly $-1 \leq \cos x \leq x$, so I'm already restricted to $[-1,1]$. Further, if $x \in [-1,0)$, then $\cos x > 0$ but $x < 0$, so $\cos x \neq 0$, so I'm only concerned with $[0,1]$. Every argument for this I have seen uses the contraction principle, though I don't have access to it yet and can't use it.

Are there any other ways to approach this?

Comment: What about all the times $\cos x \geq x$ ? Such as $x=0$, etc.. The first inequality is already flawed. But you do have the correct interval - the way to prove a unique fixed point is with the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Does $\cos$ have only one complex fixed point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x) = x - \cos x$ on $[-1,1]$. Then, $f^\prime (x) = 1 + \sin (x)$. For $x \in [-1,1]$, $f^\prime (x) > 0$. Furthermore, $f(0) < 0$ and $f(1) > 0$. Thus, by the intermediate value theorem, $f(x)$ has a root, but since $f^\prime > 0$, this root must be unique. We conclude that $\cos x$ admits a unique fixed point.

Comment: I can follow everything up to the existence of the root. How, though, does $f' > 0$ imply uniqueness?

Comment: As you identified, we restrict ourselves to $[-1,1]$. If $x_0$ is a root of $f$, then $f^\prime > 0$ implies that $f(x) > 0$ for $x > x_0$ and $f(x) < 0$ for $x < x_0$. Thus, if $x \neq x_0$, $x$ is not a root.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!